# Pre-java5: Singleton pattern: Double checked Locking vs Static factory method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

**Pre-JSE5:**

What is the difference between the following two ways of implementing a Singleton design pattern in Pre-JSE5?  In my opinion both are lazy loading only.

Even the static factory method is NOT lazy loading, what else is the difference?

**Double checked locking method:**

```
public class Singleton {
  private static volatile Singleton sic; 
  private Singleton() {}

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (sic == null) {
      // Let's make it thread safe using 'synchronized'
      synchronized(Singleton.class) {
        if (sic == null) {
          sic = new Singleton();        
        }
      }
    }
    return sic;
  }
}
```

**Static Factory method**

```
public class Singleton_StaticFactory {
  private static final Singleton_StaticFactory s = new Singleton_StaticFactory();
  private Singleton_StaticFactory() {}
  public static Singleton_StaticFactory getInstance() {
    return s;
  }
}
```

**Update**

Russell Zahniser explained in his answer about why the static factory implementation load the singleton early, in an unwanted fashion, when some other static method, if present, accessed prior to the 'getInstance' method.  So, unlike what I stated above, both are not the same in-terms of 'lazy initialization'.

I would still like to know if there are any other differences.

Comment: still on java 1.4? switch job unless they pay you very well...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking goes over this extensively

Comment: @zhong.j.yu The way this question is worded makes me think it's an academic or job interview question, because there is a specific difference in pre-java5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Java 1.5, there was no happens-before edge between a write to `volatile` field and a read from that same field. So, let's say thread-A calls `getInstance()`, sees `sic == null` and instantiates a new `Singleton` and assigns it to `sic`. A bit later, thread-B calls `getInstance()`, sees `sic != null` and returns it *without going through the `synchronized` block*. In this case, there is *no* happens-before edge between thread-A creating `sic` and thread-B reading it. That means that unless `Singleton` is thread safe even in the face of unsafe publication (which most objects are not), there is a race condition and the code is not thread-safe.

Furthermore, one of the ways to make an object thread-safe in the absence of safe publication is to mark all of its fields `final`. This ensures that any object that reads one of those `final` fields will see its state as it was at the end of the constructor (as long as you don't leak `this` outside of the constructor). But that guarantee was itself only added in Java 1.5. This means that before Java 1.5, there really wasn't any way to make an object safe in the absence of safe publication, and so the double-checked lock will always be unsafe.

All of this only applies if your singleton has state, of course -- otherwise, there's no state to need to publish thread-safely!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that double-check locking doesn't work reliably in Java 1.4.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

or Java Concurrency in Practice, section 16.2

The long answer is what @yshavit said.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `Singleton_StaticFactory` has any other static methods (or static fields, or public constructors), then calling them will trigger loading that class and initializing the singleton. So in that case the two are not exactly equivalent; otherwise they are.

Comment: He talks about pre-java5.  DCL (double checked locking) had a major flaw in the compiler.

Comment: +1. I agree with the comment by Russel Zahniser about why the static factory implementation won't be loading lazily when some other static method in the singleton class is accessed.  Thank you!  I would still wait for other comments/answers to see if there are any other differences.

Comment: DMoses is right -- they are **not** equivalent pre-1.5, which was part of the question. Specifically, in 1.4 and below, the `Singleton_StaticFactory` is thread-safe while the double-checked locking is not.